# How can I compile a Visual C# 2008 program that includes an access database?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, ms-access, compilation

I have tried creating an install file but it never includes the database in the output, I have run into this problem a few times and most of the answers I find online are too cryptic for me to wrap my head around.

Comment: What program are you using to create the install package?

Comment: The built in visual studio one, Build>>Publish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Project menu, select Add existing item, change the file type to Data Files and select your database. Then go to your project properties, in the publish tab, click the Application Files button and make sure your access file is include.

Comment: That did it, I didn't have it set to data file in the publish list thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you include your MDB as a resource (Properties -> Build Action -> Embedded Resource) you can extract it using: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(name);`

See here for a complete sample (that also decompresses): 
http://code.google.com/p/videobrowser/source/browse/trunk/MtnFrameGrabProvider/Plugin.cs